# What is a Rust systest?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I [sometimes](https://github.com/alexcrichton/curl-rust/tree/master/systest) [see](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-jni-sys/tree/master/systest) that a Rust crate has a folder called `systest`. I guess that the name stands for "system test", but I can't find any documentation of this.

My questions are:

- What is the purpose of a `systest`? Just testing that a crate compiles fine, or also testing that some code in another crate runs fine?
- What are the rules to follow when writing a `systest`? Is it just a crate in a folder called `systest`?
- Why does the `lib.rs` in `systest/src` seem to always include a file `all.rs` generated from `build.rs`?

Comment: I have never seen a `systest`. Can you give an example project that has one?

Comment: I added two links

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`systest` is not a standard name used in Rust or Cargo. However, it is the name suggested by the documentation for [ctest](https://github.com/alexcrichton/ctest), which performs automated testing for FFI bindings. build.rs uses `ctest` to generate the all.rs file which contains the tests, and this is included from the main file.

According to the documentation, the tests generate include ensuring that all function signatures, constant values, struct layout/alignment, type size/alignment, etc., all match their C equivalent.